# Как обозначить "содержит эту последовательность символов" в регулярном выражении?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть такие строки

```
<link href = "css/style.min.css">

<script src = "js/script.min.js"></script>

<main class="page">

</main>
```

Хочу найти только пути к файлам с помощью регулярных выражений. У меня получилось найти весь текст в кавычках с помощью такого регулярного выражения:

```
(`|"|')(.*)(`|"|')
```

Теперь мне надо найти только тот текст, который содержит `.css` `.js`. Я попробовал сделать такое выражение:

```
(`|"|')[.jscss](.*)(`|"|')
```

но оно не исключило строку с `class` так как `[]` означают "содержит любой из этих символов". Есть ли выражение "содержит эту последовательность символов"?

Comment: к вопросу не относится, но в регулярке ``[.jscss]`` каждый символ достаточно указать только один раз. Нет никакого смысла указывать s трижды, на результат это не повлияет, а вот скорость может даже и замедлит.

Comment: @Эникейщик Вы правы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, Вы правы - можно чуть подсократить:

```
/[^`"']+?\.(css|js)/gi
```

Чтобы вместе с кавычками:

```
/([`"'])\S+?\.(css|js)\1/gi
```

Comment: а если надо вместе с кавычками?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH: дополнил

Answer (score 1):

Такое выражение подошло, но оно с кучей скобок:

```
/'|`|"(.*\.js|.*\.css)(`|"|')/g
```

Если предложите более читаемый вариант, буду рад.

Update:

Со строками типа:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.min.css">
```

это не работает. Данное выражение выделяет все, начиная с первой кавычки, а мне нужен именно путь, поэтому, основываясь на ответе UModeL я дополнил его выражение, но опять получилась куча скобок:

```
([`"'])\w?:?((\.{1,2})?\/{1,2})?\/?(css|js).+?\.(css|js)\1/gi
```

Тут, учитывая, что файл стиля или скрипта находится в соответстующей папке, мы сначала ищем ее название и берем только те кавычки, в которых это название идет сразу после кавычки. Также учел случаи, когда может быть записан абсолютный и относительный пути. Если не хотите учитывать все варианты пути, то возьмите эту часть выражения:

```
/(css|js).+?\.(css|js)\1/gi
```

Comment: Разберитесь сначала, какие входные данные и какой конечный результат ожидается, а затем задавайте вопрос. Обновил свой ответ.